# ArrayList to update HTML Table

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, arraylist

Good Evening,
I've got to update my already existing Table with the data of an ArrayList, which consists of Database data. The List is implemented like this:

```
ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Termine");
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
while(rs1.next()){
    String veranName = rs1.getString(1);
    String terminid = rs1.getString(2); 
    list.add(new String[]{veranName, terminid});
    }
```

Now i don't know how i can iterate through the List in Javascript or HTML and update my HTML Table with these Elements.

I wanted to use this:

```
ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Termine");
List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
while(rs1.next()){
    String veranName = rs1.getString(1);
    String terminid = rs1.getString(2); 
    updateTable(veranName,terminid);
    }
```

With `updateTable(vname, vid){document.getElementById(vid).value=vname;}`
But this didnt work, because the DOC operations are in Javascript and it wasn't found (at least i think thats why). The Code belongs to a JSP Webapplication, in which i have to code something like a weekly calendar, which is displayed as a html table.

Has anyone got a Solution for my matter?
Future Thanks :)

Comment: What is the context here -- are you running the query from a servlet or a JSP or where? You cannot call JavaScript (`document.getElementById`) directly from Java code.

Comment: @MickMnemonic I edited my post. I know that i can't call Javascript from Java Code, but i tried to call a function, which was defined in the <script></script> Part of the JSP Page, which didn't work aswell. So i don't really know how to edit already existing html table cells with java code.

Answer (score 0):

The Java code that fetches the rows from the database is performed in an `Action` or `Controller` class depending the the technology you use. You have to add the list to the session attributes if you want to use it in a JSP:

```
List<String[]> appointments = new ArrayList<>();
// ... fill the list
request.setAttribute("termine", appointments);
```

In the JSP you retrieve the list from the request attributes and can iterate over it, eg:

```
<% 
List<String[]> appointments = (List<String[]>) request.getAttribute("termine");
for (String[] appointment : appointments) {
%>
  <div>veranName: <%= appointment[0] %></div>
  <div>terminid: <%= appointment[1] %></div>
<%
}
%>
```